# Android - ViewModel dependent on intent, problematic with back button

Tags: android, android-activity, viewmodel

I have an activity A that displays a group based on a given id, this id is retrieved from an intent.
the problem is that this activity A also starts an activity B(for adding members to the group)ץ
When I click the back button in B, it destroys activity A and recreates it, and when I try to retrieve the id from the intent there is no id so it gets a default value of -1, which means I can't display the group because I've "lost" the id. So it's very easy to understand that my code design is not so good.
How can I fix it? Is there a practice that I need to implement? thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I've checked and the code works for API 27 and API 29(Q), but API R whhich is the newest is the only one when the bug occurs.

Activity A code(I plan on moving the regions to seperate functions, please ignore it, the id retreiving happens in the beginning:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_group_standings);
        Log.d("TAG", "Standings has been created")
        //region gets Data
        Log.d("TAG", "Receives data");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setTitle(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_GROUP_TITLE));
        groupID = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_GROUP_ID, -1);
        //endregion;
        //region sets FAB
        FloatingActionButton playGameFABtn = (findViewById(R.id.play_game_button));
        playGameFABtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeamAssignmentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(TeamAssignmentActivity.EXTRA_GROUP_ID, groupID);
                intent.putExtra(TeamAssignmentActivity.EXTRA_PLAYERS_DETAILS, (Serializable) standings);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RUN_GAME_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        //endregion
        //region sets group end case(can't open)
        if (groupID == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Couldn't open group", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        //endregion
        //region sets RecyclerView standings
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.standings_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //endregion
        //region sets recycler-view background opacity - 180/255
        Drawable background = recyclerView.getBackground();
        background.setAlpha(180);
        //endregion
        //region sets standings adapter
        final GroupStandingsDetailAdapter groupStandingsAdapter = new GroupStandingsDetailAdapter();
        groupStandingsAdapter.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(groupStandingsAdapter);
        //endregion
        //region sets ViewModel
        groupStandingsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new GroupStandingsViewModelFactory(getApplication(), groupID)).get(GroupStandingsViewModel.class);
        groupStandingsViewModel.getAllStandingsDetail().observe(this, new Observer<List<StandingsDetail>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<StandingsDetail> standingsDetails) {
                groupStandingsAdapter.submitList(standingsDetails);
                standings = standingsDetails;
            }
        });
        //endregion
        //TODO: add longClickListener for group standings - editing and removing
        //region sets LongClickListener TODO: add edit options for long click on standings
        groupStandingsAdapter.setOnItemLongClickListener(new GroupStandingsDetailAdapter.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(StandingsDetail standingsDetail) {
            }
        });
        //endregion
    }
```

Comment: Going from Activity A to B and pressing the back button should not destroy your previous activity!  what do you mean by "when I click the back button in B, it destroys activity A and recreates "?

Comment: I mean that I've checked it and when clicking on the next button in destroys the last previous activity note that it only happens on API R, on API 27 for example it doesn't happen to me.

Comment: I think you can use shared preferences (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) to store the id's and then access them as per your need. Also have a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm